# Possible to add a bidirectional LSTM after a 2D CNN in Keras?

Tags: python

I am using 2D CNN with input shape (20,20,1). Can I add LSTM layer after 2D CNN layer?

```
nb_classes = 2
nb_kernels = 3
nb_pools = 2
def cnn_model():
model = Sequential()

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape = ( 20, 20,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(4, nb_kernels, nb_kernels, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(strides = (nb_pools, nb_pools), dim_ordering = 'th'))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, nb_kernels, nb_kernels, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(strides = (nb_pools, nb_pools), dim_ordering = 'th'))
model.add(LSTM(28))(20, 5)

model.add(Dense(nb_classes)) #fully connected layer
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the dimensions of the output of the Conv layer before adding the LSTM layer.

In your case the problem is due to; the dimensions of the output of Conv layer is 4, but the input dimension expected by the LSTM layer is 3.

So you need to add a Dense layer between the Conv and LSTM layers.

Comment: @ Henry: I added the dense layer (i.e., model.add(Dense(1))) between the suggested layers but received the same error.